# How to tell when a view has become active

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm using a navigationController to push a new view onto the stack. Once I'm done with that view I pop it. I want the original or root view at the bottom of the stack which then becomes active to know when this has happened to it can call a method on itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options

**1.** implement -(void) `viewWillAppear:animated`: This is often a useful strategy for knowing that a view is about to become visible. If you are always doing the same thing when this happens, then this is quick and easy.

**2.** Send a [NSNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This is useful when you want your underlying view to perform some action in response to a particular event happening elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use the viewWillAppear delegate. It is called right before showing the view.